# React & Canvas: changing state is breaking Canvas functions

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I am trying to use a parent component to control animations in a child Canvas element. Specifically I want an animation to happen when a user inputs a correct answer.

It works until the user changes the state in the parent component, and then it no longer works.

I've made a stripped-back, minimal version of my code here to show my issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-leaf-08jqvy?file=/src/App.js

My desired behaviour is that the red box bounces when a user clicks submit. That happens if they don't type anything in the input box, but as soon as you enter anything into there - changing state and re-rendering the component - the button no longer triggers the animation in the Canvas child component.

As far as I can tell, the issue is to do with changing the state when inputing text. If I make a version where the input is just assigned to a variable, it works fine, but I need to be able to use state and re-render other parts of it.

I have put a console.log in the jump() function, so I can see that it is being called, but no animation is taking place in the canvas.

I assume that what's happening is that everything is being re-rendered when the state changes, and so the useRef is no longer tracking to the right thing.

Things I've tried:

- putting the canvas in a memoized component to prevent it from re-rendering
- using eventlisteners to see if I can trigger the animations in other ways - keydown ones work, but I need the user to be able to type, so I tried other ones (like hashchange or audio.play) but neither of those worked.

You can see the thing I'm actually trying to build here: https://papaya-platypus-86565f.netlify.app/play Basically users answer questions and an animation plays depending on whether they're right or wrong, to give it a game-y feel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your red box as well as your reasoning. Yes, the input state changing on keystroke is causing the entire App component to re-render. Note that your `App.js` component has a lot going on (all good stuff), such as your Box class instantiation, your canvas instantiation, etc.

The key is to break your components into smaller parts, particularly separating stateful components from non-stateful components. We don't want your canvas re-mounting on every input change, so we make them sibling components!

Here's a working example of your code, just in smaller components:

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-julien-d3n4zm

I hope this helps.